# Calculating the distance to the next available IP address

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, ipv6, subnet

Let's say I want to assign IPv6 addresses to people from the 2001:0DB8::/32 range.  Most are given out sequentially, but some are non-sequential.  This DB table shows which addresses have already been assigned.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                 Address                 |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0003 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0009 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0F00:0001 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0F00:0002 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Notice that it's sparsely filled - the first 3 are taken, then there are 5 available addresses until the next one is taken, then a gap of several million addresses before another one is taken.

What I want to do is assign users the **next available address**, starting from the beginning of the subnet.  In this case it would be easy enough to start at the beginning, discover that there's no record for 2001:0DB8::4 yet, and use that one.  But eventually the next available address may be thousands or millions of steps away from the start of the subnet.  Walking through the database one address at a time would be a bad idea.

I thought of adding another field to the table so that each address indicates how many available addresses there are between itself and the next one in the list:

```
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                 Address                 | Steps to next addr |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 |                  1 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 |                  1 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0003 |                  6 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0009 |           15728632 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0F00:0001 |                  2 |
| 2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0F00:0003 |                    |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

but I'm not sure that helps me.  If an IP address is assigned somewhere in the middle of a sparse section, I'll still have to calculate how many steps there are from that address to the next one in sequence, and then go back to the closet assigned address before the new one and correct its "steps to next addr" as well.  Still seems like a slow process.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is almost certainly a terrible way to assign IPv6 addresses to begin with. I _hope_ it's merely a (poorly conceived) homework assignment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm genuinely interested in how you would best come up with an address assignment algorithm. Probably off-topic as an answer for this question (as it deals with augmenting an already existing IPAM database) but would look forward to seeing it as an answer to a brand new question.

Comment: @JeremyVisser That's what DHCP is for...

Comment: @NathanC Not even the same argument, man. Not going there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solvable by just slightly tweaking your approach here. I'm assuming that the reason why you would like to fill unused gaps here is because you have an existing sparsely populated database that you would like to make better use of.

Keep your original table, but separately store a `next_address` field (say, in a `Settings` table). When you first deploy your code, the `next_address` will begin at `2001:db8::1`.

Your `get_next_address()` function would then look something like this:

```
def initialise_settings():
    if not Settings.exists('next_address'):
         Settings.set('next_address', IPv6('2001:db8::1'))

def get_next_address():

    next = Settings.get('next_address')

    # Check for already filled rows -- breaks loop upon finding gap
    while Database.row_exists({'Address': next}):
        next += 1

    Settings.set('next_address', next + 1)
    return next

get_next_address() # 2001:db8::4
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::5
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::6
# ...
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::f00:0
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::f00:2
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::f00:4
get_next_address() # 2001:db8::f00:5
```

Comment: Yes, I have inherited a DB where the assignment strategy varies.  Most often the next available IP address is what's wanted, but a good chunk of addresses are already assigned based on factors like a device's MAC address, etc.
 
I think I understand your solution -- you are storing the actual next available address rather than the steps to the next address -- but won't the next_address calculation still have a major slowdown if there is a gap of several million addresses between two assigned addresses?  But perhaps that's unavoidable at least for the initial run.

Comment: If there is a large block of already allocated addresses that you run into, then yes, it would take time to iterate through that. But I think the simplicity of the algorithm outweighs the downsides. You're guaranteed to get there in the end, and it's relatively easy to understand. Ease of understanding carries intrinsic reliability with it. :-)